# Strange behavior of bitwise NOT (~)

Tags: c++, c, types, bit-manipulation

How do I explain the following behavior?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

       unsigned char a = 8;

       cerr << "a: " << (int)a << '\n';

       unsigned char b = (~a) >> 6;

       cerr << "b: " << (int)b << '\n';

       unsigned char c = (~a);
       c = c >> 6;

       cerr << "c: " << (int)c << '\n';

       return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 8
b: 255
c: 3
```

After further testing it seems that `(~a)` becomes an `int` rather than `unsigned char`. This is why the `1`'s get shifted in.

What's going on?

EDIT: My compiler is just standard gcc 4.1.2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All arithmetic and bitwise operators in C always widen their arguments to at least `int` if they were originally shorter integral types. That's just how the language is defined. The language specification calls this the "integral promotion".

(The underlying reason for this is to make it easier to implement C on architectures where the hardware does not support efficient operations on shorter quantities than a full machine word. Of course, it's also partly just because it has always worked that way and cannot be changed without breaking a lot of existing code that depends on this behavior).

Comment: The word "promotion" should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Is there a C standard reference for this? I'd be very interested in the entire section about this.

Comment: C++03 §5.3.1/9: "The operand of `~` shall have integral or enumeration type; the result is the one’s complement of its operand. Integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand."

Comment: And C99 §6.5.3.3/4: "The result of the `~` operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression `~E` is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus `E`."

Comment: See also C99 §6.3 Conversions: 
_Several operators convert operand values from one type to another automatically. This
subclause specifies the result required from such an implicit conversion, as well as those
that result from a cast operation (an explicit conversion)._  The relevant part of the section covers 4 pages of the standard.

Comment: This is the kind of behavior that a liberal use of masking helps to prevent.  For instance unsigned char b = ((~a) & 0xff) >> 6;  There are enough gray areas and options in the standards that it is difficult to remember all the rules so it is usually best to just explicitly write what you want as specifically as possible to remove as much ambiguity as you can.

Answer (score 2):

`~a = 0xFFFFFFF7`, so `b = (~a) >> 6` results in `b = 0xFF`; In case of c we have `c = (~a);` resulting in `c = 0xF7`, therefore `c>>6` will be 3. Henning Makholm explains integer promotion nicely above. This [article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/language_ref/cplr066.html) is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 8

~a = -9 (int)

~a >> 6 = -1 (int)

(unsigned char)-1 = 255
```

Answer (score 1):

because this line...

```
unsigned char b = (~a) >> 6;
```

compiler build the temporary var is signed char **(~a)** and after the shift right and **LSB** byte  b is **0xff**

but this lines...

```
   unsigned char c = (~a);
   c = c >> 6;
```

compiler not needed to build the temporary var and **(~a)** value is **0x7f**, and after the shift right c is **0x03**